# bootable CD to upgrade firmware

Tags: boot, firmware, optical-media

We have a DL380 G6 and we want to put the latest BIOS firmware on a bootable CD-ROM.

The bootable USB installer that HP provides works great, but we want a bootable CD-ROM instead, because we have many servers and a CD is easier to duplicate.

The BIOS firmware we want to install is not available on the latest HP Firmware Maintenance CD.

I've been trying for a couple of hours now and wasted 6 CDs to no avail. Can anyone suggest a workable solution?

Many thanks!
Toast

Comment: Disregard; I was wrong about the Firmware CD...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a bootable CD-ROM you need to prepare the disc. You will need to add Bootfiles to the disc. [Here is](http://www.webtree.ca/windowsxp/create_a_bootable_cddvd_or_usb.htm) a simple description of how to do this. You will even find a link there to download the correct bootimage. I did this 3-4 times yet and always used this short howto and the bootimage linked there. Your CD-ROM will appear as drive "A:" after booting. There also is a way to do this with some other images, which provide CD-ROM support, but I never did that, so I can´t tell you how good this works.

Comment: Cool. Where's the simple description?

Comment: "Here is" is a link ;-)

Comment: Doh! :)
EDIT: Thanks mate, those instructions are just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3884083&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884082&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4064#12212

(I selected Win2k8_R2 and went to the BIOS section)

Comment: that's interesting, I noticed that the first 2 items don't even need to run from a separate bootable media, you can just execute them directly from the OS, is this true?

Comment: @ToastMan Yes, that is what HP means by "Online" ROM Flash.

Comment: According to the Installation Instructions, that is true.  (It's a Self-Extracting executable.)  Just about every Proliant I've seen (Mostly 380's and 580s, some 360's and 760's, all from G1-G6) has had a redundant ROM.  I assume the ones that update from the OS update the one that's not in use currently and switch to it on reboot...

Comment: ah! that makes a lot of sense. So I guess I don't even need a bootable CDROM, but it still pisses me off that I was unable to create one.

Comment: Put in a support case with them and request it.  Just state that you'd like a disk iso for use with CDs or iLO

Answer (score 1):

HP makes a firemware maintenance DVD to upgrade all firmware on newer servers, not just BIOS.

Here is the link:
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=1844067&prodNameId=1844068&swEnvOID=181&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-3380ae888f86436aac54c149eb

*Edit: Blah, read too fast. I'll leave the answer here anyways, in case someone else tries to search serverfault for the link.*